# ASP.NET Datagrid : How to style?

Tags: asp.net

Can any one tell me how to do styling for an asp.net datagrid control.I have the following requirements. I want to know to which proprties these style classes to be applied

1 . Header Row should have border in top and bottom.No Left and Right borders.
2 . Want to have a line seperator between each column in the header row.Not needed for Left and Right.LEt that be open
3 .Need to apply different styles for each column values.How to mention various classes for different columns ?

I am searching for a asolution which renders in allbrowsers with same effect

Answer (score 3):

You can add a  section in the `<asp:DataGrid>` tag like this:

```
<HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" BackColor="SaddleBrown" ForeColor="Ivory" />
```

Or you can set the style in the column templates ike this:

```
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Account Number"
DataField="AccountNumber" ReadOnly="True"
HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="True" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

I think that you will have better luck with the second approach. I have encountered problems with some of the `<HeaderStyle>` tag styles not being applied when it's only under the `<asp:DataGrid>` tag.

If you want to carry the same style over to other DataGrids, you can create a skin so you'll have the same header style everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the 4guysfromrolla.com [article series](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135207/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040502-1.aspx) on ASP.net DataGrids. [Part 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111600/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041702-1.aspx) talks about styling DataGrids.

Answer (score 1):

The DataGrid and DataTable controls renders out tables. So use CSS:

```
table { ... }
thead { ... }
tbody { ... }
tfoot { ... }
tr { ... }
td { ... }
th { ... }
```

There's plenty of elements to target.

... Here's a bit of code to get you started:

```
/* target table-rows in the header element of a table and modify border-styles */
thead tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Can you apply borders to table rows? I thought one had to do that at the cell level.

Answer (score -1):

Use the CssClass property of the grid to give the table a css class. To get different behavior out of the leading and ending elements also apply a class to the column header and cells. Then use CSS to style the elements of the table. IE:

ASPX:

```
<asp:DataGrid CssClass="grid" . . . .
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderClass = "first" ItemClass = "first" . . . .
(other columns)
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderClass = "last" ItemClass = "last" . . .
```

CSS:

```
table.grid th { border: solid 1px black}
table.grid th.first {border-left: 0px}
table.grid th.last {border-right: 0px}
```

No need to use the ASP.NET styles, mainly because you can get much slicker with CSS and not have bloated code.