# DataGrid gridline colors

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

How do you set the colors and width of the gridlines in a DataGrid, in my DataGrid I cannot get the gridlines to show up or the rowlines.

```
            <asp:DataGrid ID="OpenGrid" runat="server" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyField="InvoiceID"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both"
                            Width="65%" BorderWidth="1px">
```

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991190/asp-net-datagrid-how-to-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `<ItemStyle BorderColor="Blue" />`

**update**

if you are familiar with .css you can take this concept and apply it.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <style>
        .exampleDiv table
        {
            border-color: Blue;
        }

        .exampleDiv td
        {
            border-color: Blue;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">   
    <div class="exampleDiv">
        <asp:DataGrid ID="dgTest" runat="server">
        </asp:DataGrid>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: the datagrid still doesn't display vertical or horizontal lines

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting `BoderColor`, set `BorderStyle="Solid"` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Mike: You are making progress :)

Comment: still doesn't explain columns

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid control ultimately render as HTML table. So before you continue looking for a problem with a control make sure that you don't have any CSS rules which are overwriting the control's definitions. For example if you have:

```
table {
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

then you won't see any vertical or horizontal border lines...

Bottom line if you have included any CSS definitions for table make sure they are not messing with your DataGrid rendering...